# Change language in whole app not working with Handler

Tags: android, android-intent, handler, splash-screen, multiple-languages

I have `SplashActivity` and `MainActivity` and the default device language is English. In `SplashActivity` I change the default language of application to vi(Vietnamese). I am using 2 way to move from SplashActivity to MainActivity that I have showed in the code below.
I have tested many time very carefully but I still don't know this problem
Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        changeDefaultLanguageConfigLanguage("vi");
        moveToMain();
        ...
    }
    private void changeDefaultLanguageConfigLanguage(String language) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.locale = locale;

        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    public void moveToMain() {

        /*
           Way 1: The language in MainActivity change
        */  
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(mainIntent);

        /*
           Way 2: The language in MainActivity don't change
        */ 

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {@
            Override
            public void run() {


                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);

                //finish();

                //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
         <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you have to recreate your activity in order for the configuration change to take effect. You can use `Activity.recreate()` (introduced in API 11) for this.

I haven't tried it yet, but to avoid having to recreate the activity I would try including `locale` in the activity's `configChanges` property.

Comment: If my app only have MainActivity, then if I want to change language in MainActivity I need to reload MainActivity.
But in my situation, I have create SplashActivity for change the language so I do not need to reload MainActivity
You see in `Way 1 in my code`, it work so I think reload activity here is not a good solution

Comment: My guess is that with the second way the configuration change doesn't get handled. By moving to MainActivity, the current UI is refreshed and that automatically handles the configuration change. By waiting three seconds I can imagine that the configuration change is ignored. 

Did you try including configChanges="locale" in your manifest yet? Maybe it'll help.